# Signed Offer for New Position & Promoted at Old, Negotiate?

Tags: new-job, promotion

While going through the hiring process for a new job, I was promoted (25% increase) and most of the reasons I wanted to leave were corrected. Can I negotiate the new jobs signed offer letter?

** NOTE: Current job does not know I was looking to leave.

Comment: Did you accept the offer? Do you want to stay? Do you want to use the promotion at your current employer to (re)negotiate with the new company?

Comment: So you got money and most reasons to leave corrected.   Do you really want to take chances with an unknown AND renegotiate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is open to negotiation, but it is pretty unlikely they will budge.

Consider that you've *already* gone through the negotiation phase (whether you negotiated or not), both sides accepted the terms and they're formalized the offer.

If you go back now, how do you think they would feel? Let's flip it around. Suppose they already sent you the offer letter, then a day later they sent you **another** one, with worse terms (for you). How would that feel? Would you still consider the job, or would you think *they must think I'm a sucker and are trying to play me to see how much they can get*?

One thing to note: if you let your original job know you were looking, or you have an offer, **you're dead**: you can kiss your future at the original job goodbye. You will be moved to the top of the 'layoff' list and the bottom of the 'raises and promotions' list.

Also—unlikely, but I've seen it happen—if original company finds out who offered you the position, they can torpedo your new gig with a few well-placed phone calls. Best advice in this area is to keep quiet about the new job until after you start, if you intend upon taking that job.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to renegotiate, be prepared for them walking out even assuming the current offer. You can do it, but it is a risky move. If you feel like your grievances were resolved at the current place you may want to stick around - many times the grass isn't all much greener on the other side of the fence.